# How to write to a file and allow users to download the file in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm kinda new to PHP. How do i write to a temporary file resulting data from a mysql query and allow users to download it.

Comment: You probably shouldn't. In most cases you should just return the data in the HTTP response and not write to the file system at all.

Comment: Just echo the data to the screen. If you want to have a save-as dialogue box, search for "content disposition attachment php" - _loads_ of info out there on this.

Comment: @Quentin how do i get that done?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably best streaming it straight to the client, rather than saving it to a temporary file and providing the user with a link (depending on exactly what you're doing).

Something like:

```
<?php
header('content-type: text/plain');
file_get_contents('/your/temporary/file');
?>
```

Assuming your output is plain text, obviously.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to spend some time reading some basic PHP tutorials to get yourself started. PHP has lots of file related functions that you could use to achieve what you want to do - there isn't one single approach I would recommend. It all depends on the specific context and requirements of your project. 
W3 schools might be a good place to start or the php manual. Look at methods like fopen, fwrite, fread, file_put_contents and file_get_contents.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$filename = 'temporary.file';
$file = '/path/to/temporary.file';
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
readfile($file);
```